# Relation between IP address and AS Number

Tags: networking, ip-address

What is the relation between IP addresses and AS Numbers (Autonomous Sytems Number)? Is there a mapping somewhere?

For eg:- If my ipconfig looks like

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : XXXX.YYY.edu

Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::989f:1084:e738:41d8p6

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.103.19.216

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.252.0

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.103.16.11

```
Can anyone decipher which AS am I on?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are online databases like [the one of the ARIN](http://itools.com/tool/arin-whois-domain-search). Simply enter an IP address.

Or you can do a `whois` on the IP address yourself, and will usually find the AS number in a field like `origin` or `OriginAS`.

For example: Determining the primary IP address of Stack Overflow, and looking for the AS it belongs to:

```
$ dig -t A stackoverflow.com | grep -v -e '^;' -e '^$'
stackoverflow.com.      291     IN      A       198.252.206.16

$ whois 198.252.206.16 | grep -i origin
OriginAS:       AS25791
```